# Is there a way to increase the 4Gb limit for a/v recordings set by windows7?

Tags: windows-7, video, recording

I have a situation where I am trying to record my screen, both the video and the audio.  I have recently acquired hardware that works with software that the company makes to be able to do just that.  After recording about 30 mins, I stop and open the folder where the recorded file is to be saved.  In that folder I find not 1, but 3 files.  Confused, I start examining the files and quickly learned that the recording I made got automatically split into three shortened files instead of just the one I thought I was making.  2 were both exactly 3.8 GBs in size (a little over 11 1/2 mins each) and the 3rd was 1.6Gbs (the remaining recording time).  I checked through all the settings and options on the software I was using and found no mention of recording size limits.

So, after looking for answers via blogs on the website for the software, the only thing I found was mention of my operating system being the culprit of the issue.  I learned that Windows 7 limits the file size of a/v recordings to 4 GBs:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mpeg-4-file-sink?redirectedfrom=MSDN

  (this doc mentions the file size limit under the Limitations section)

Further searches on this matter have come up empty.  I am using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.  All my hard drives partitions are **all NTFS, no FAT32**.  I have over 1.3Tbs on the drive I am recording to.  I would love to be able to record more than 4 GBs of a/v without it getting broke up into multiple 3.8 GB files.

Comment: "I have recently learned that windows7 limits the file size of a/v recordings to 4Gbs."- Where exactly did you learn this?  The only reason this might be true is due to the fact you have a FAT32 partition.  I have no problem creating audio video files larger than 4 GB on my offline Windows 7 systems

Comment: Your question still indicate what software you are using.  The software itself is limiting the size of the video, if there isn’t an option to create larger files, then you will need to use different software.  Your question cannot be answered in its current form.  If you provide enough information to identify the software, and remove the rant, about the reasonable request for more information then I can answer the question.  This problem isn’t due to Windows 7

Comment: the software is GeForce Experience

Comment: Based on the link you provided, it looks like the MPEG-4 File Sink has a limit of 4GB output files, not Windows 7 specifically. See if there is an option to change the file output from GeFore Experience.

Comment: I have found no mention of recording size limits with that software.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I found nothing that would allow me to change the file recording type.  Maybe I just need better software.  Thank you

Comment: It seems like it.

Comment: @thefatherofZEN - There probably isn’t an option since it’s a deliberate limitation of the codex you have selected. [Use different software](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/discover/166792/recording-file-size-/)

Comment: @MichaelFrank The MPEG-4 File Sink is a component of Microsoft Media Foundation  which is a component of Windows that GeForce Experience depends on. The MSDN link provided by OP states that Windows 8 has lifted this limitation. It's not a GeForce Experience limitation.

Comment: @gronostaj That's true, but the question title refers to the limit being set by Windows 7, which it's not. There are plenty of other applications that can create larger than 4GB files on Windows, just not in the MPEG-4 format.

Comment: @MichaelFrank It is caused by a limitation of a particular Windows 7 component. In Windows 8 that component was modified to remove this limitation, so it certainly was caused by the Windows 7 implementation. Other software isn't affected because it's not using that particular component.

Comment: @gronostaj Fair point. +1